# Import events list and events detail from multiple feeds and combine them

Tags: import, feed

I've got an external XML feed which contains a list with events and some basic info. Let's say: feeds/events
Every event has an unique ID and with that ID I can get the details of every event.
Something like: feeds/events/[UNIQUE_ID]

Is it possible to import and combine the details to every event and store it in a channel? I've used Datagrab before but I don't see how to combine something like this. I was thinking about a custom script to combine the two and output this so Datagrab could import it. But maybe there is an easier way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set one column as a KEY in Datagrab, when an import is performed and the KEY field matches then record is updated rather than created.

So in your case if you have two sources, you run the first one -- it creates the channel entries, then you run the second import it updates the entries which have the matching KEY (your UNIQUE_ID).

Comment: Assuming the ID doesn't already exist as another entry from another channel'.

Comment: The second import needs the unique_id in order to get the details. So for every event a new import must be created. Thats the url + unique_id.